# How to check if cells having the same value in the same column in database system sql server?

Tags: sql, database

am having a problem to know if two or more cells having the same value.
Ex:
column contains name of authors and another column contains the city the live in ..
am trying to know the names of authors living in the same city ..
so I want to check on the city column to know if the have same city or not but I don't know the syntax .. :)

```
select authors.au_fname , authors.au_lname ,city -- to present the first & last name of author
from authors
Where -- I don't know the condition here
```

Comment: What output do you expect? Can you give an example?

Comment: column authors contains names
column city contains the city they live in

there are authors who live in the same city
so am expecting to get the names of these authors with the common city they live in

Comment: That's not an example, but I think Hélio has your answer.

Comment: @SUE share your table structure. That will help people to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
select a1.au_fname , a1.au_lname, a2.au_fname , a2.au_lname, city    
from authors a1 inner join authors a2 on a1.id <> a2.id
where a1.city= a2.city
```

**Explanation:**

One has to compare each combination of two authors, therefore the table is joined with itself   on different primary keys (I am assuming `authors.id`) . Finally, the `where` states that only authors living in the same city are to be output, filtering out authors paris not living in the same city.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to sort by the city:

```
select authors.au_fname , authors.au_lname ,city -- to present the first & last name of author
from authors
order by city
```

If you only want to select cities that have 2 or more authors, well, here is one way that works in any database:

```
select authors.au_fname , authors.au_lname ,city -- to present the first & last name of author
from authors
where city in (select city from authors group by city having count(*) >= 2)
order by city
```